# How to implement a toggle button link?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<script>
    function setSortMethod(param) {
         var sortMethod = "@sortMethod";
         var asecending = false;
         var currUrl = "";
         var currSort = "";
         var outputUrl = "";

         currSort = "sortMethod=" + param;

         if ($('#filterPending')[0].checked == false {
                outputUrl = (currSort);
         }
         window.location.href = "?" + outputUrl;
    }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="action" onclick="setSortMethod('StartDate')" value="LeaveDate">
   Leave Date
</button>
```

So I am trying to get this link button working to toggle between ascending and descending sorting order.

- ../Index?sortMethod=StartDate which sort the display data by
  ascending order
- ../Index?sortMethod=StartDate_desc will sort the display data by
  descending order

I have tried using a boolean variable toggle true/false but to no avail.

Backend c# code I already have the ViewBag with ternary

```
ViewBag.StartDate = sortMethod == "StartDate" ? "StartDate_desc" : "StartDate";
```

With switch case it will work if you manually key in the url.

But because right now I am reworking on the link button I changed from actionlink to bootstrap's button link, so I have to find some ways to get the "StartDate" parameter for this `onclick="setSortMethod('StartDate')` passed into `setSortMethod` function and try to toggle between StartDate or StartDate_desc.

Trying out razor syntax with ViewBag,

```
@{ 
    string sortMethod = ViewBag.StartDate;
}
```

but I am not sure what can I do with this.

Comment: so, when your button is clicked, you want to call setSortMethod() with sorting value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this One.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="action" onclick="setSortMethod('StartDate')" value="LeaveDate">
    Leave Date
</button>

<script>
    function setSortMethod(param) {

         var sortMethod = "";
         var asecending = false;
         var currUrl = "";
         var currSort = "";
         var outputUrl = "";

         currSort = "sortMethod=" + param;

         window.location.href += "?" + currSort
    }
</script>
```